# I am getting error log Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.163

Tags: iis, webserver

I am using Windows server 2012 and IIS 8.0 but when I run the application then I am getting below errors.

I found below errors on the production server when running the app. It is not continuously getting but whenever getting it locks the app and we can't do anything. It might be a dll conflict or might other configuration issue. Please let me know your thought so I can go ahead.

1. WAS:- A process serving application pool 'GK' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. 
   The process id was '5604'. The data field contains the error number.
2. Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time

stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16451, time
stamp: 0x50988aa6
Exception code: 0xe0434352

1. Application: w3wp.exe
   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
   Exception Info: System.Runtime.CallbackException
   Stack:
   at
   System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32,
   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at
   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

Can you please look into this if you can help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We started receiving this error after installing windows updates on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) installs some additional site bindings that caused issues for our setup.

We removed net.tcp, net.pipe, net.msmq, and msmq.formatname bindings from our website and no longer got the faulting application exception.